# How to convert month in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I'm trying to convert month text to month number in MySQL, but somehow can't fully grasp how it works. Almost as if changing the date-time format.

Suppose I have:

```
2017-OCT-15
2016-FEB-19
2015-JUL-12
```

and would love to convert it into:

```
2017-10-15
2016-02-19
2015-07-12
```

What command/function should I use? Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2017-OCT-15', '%Y-%b-%d')
```

You can find the options from [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)